# How can I get the clipping paths to be objects in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, smartobject

I'm converting a vector drawing from Bohemian Sketch to Adobe Illustrator so that I can export eps and svg, etc.

When I copy and paste from Sketch I get a bunch of clipping paths instead of objects.

Any advice on how to get those to be editable vector elements quickly?
.. there are hundreds of them.

Answer (score 2):

It *really* depends upon the artwork.

If the art is comprised of a bunch of raster images with clipping masks you are sort of stuck. You can't crop, cut, or clip raster images within Illustrator - you can only mask them.

If the art is all vector and merely contains clipping masks.....

In some cases, `Object > Flatten Transparency` will quickly "bake in" clipping masks. Beyond that, you may need to select individual masks and use `Object > Expand` followed by `Pathfinder > Crop` (the panel, not the effect menu).

This is generalizing, without seeing the file construction or layers panel expanded it's difficult to be more precise.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up just releasing the clipping mask but I'm going to remember these tips in case I need to convert other art (that's not all vector).

Comment: No problem. Simply releasing the clipping masks is a different appearance completely :)